# Error on websocket when try to use Ipython notebook in emacs

Tags: emacs, websocket, ipython, tornado, jupyter-notebook

Got some error message in buffer *Warning* when try to evaluate my code

```
Error (websocket): in callback `on-open': Cannot send message to a closed websocket: cl-struct-websocket-frame, text, "{\"header\":{\"msg_id\":\"14735853-0ed2-4ef4-8f5a-312a198dd251\", \"username\":\"username\"\, \"session\":\"ab484abf-d4e6-4f83-2c2-de1b65264780\", \"msg_type\":\"execute_request\"}, \"metadata\":{}, \"content\":{\"code\":\"__import__('sys').stdout.write(__import__('os').getcwd())\", \"silent\":true, \\"user_variables\":[], \"user_expressions\":{}, \"allow_stdin\":false}, \"parent_header\":{}}", nil, t
Error (websocket): in callback `on-open': Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
Error (websocket): in callback `on-close': Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

And on the ipython server side I saw this message

```
2014-03-05 23:24:40.760 [NotebookApp] WARNING | Cross Origin WebSocket Attempt.
2014-03-05 23:24:40.761 [tornado.application] ERROR | Uncaught exception in /kernels/2691bbe3-ce95-439b-a9ce-97ec52c80988/shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/haroldwu/Python-test/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 322, in wrapper
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/haroldwu/Python-test/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/html/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 114, in open
    raise web.HTTPError(404)
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

What I have done:

1. Upgrade all package of my python virtualenv and global environment
2. Upgrade all system package (Archlinux latest 64-bit)
3. Upgrade all emacs package
4. Search the web (but found no useful result)

Ipython notebook worked on my emacs weeks ago, but somehow it dosen't work now...
I have no experience on tornado.

Thanks for your help!!! :)

Comment: I recently started getting the same error, except with python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that emacs is not sending the `Origin` header which is checked by the Notebook WS code. See my comment https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5525 .

Quick workaround is to comment out the same origin check in your `/home/haroldwu/Python-test/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/html/base/zmqhandlers.py:114` .

You can always add logging of `parsed_origin`, `origin` and `origin_header` in `same_origin()` function in `zmqhandlers.py` and fix the emacs package accordingly.

Comment: I got another error with ein :`ein: [error] Error (parse-error) while opening notebook list at the server 8888.` I'm now trying figure out the problem. (It should be ein's own problem, maybe caused by upgrading ipython from 3.3 to 3.4) Anyway, thanks for your advice! I will try your method once ein "works" again.